# Python snmp trap

Tags: python, snmp

I have a code that sends snmp trap.By sending an snmp trap information, I am trying to listen to that information and take action according to the incoming information.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import ntforg


def send_trap(oid, value, target_ip='127.0.0.1'):
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        sendNotification(
            SnmpEngine(),
            CommunityData('public'),
            UdpTransportTarget((target_ip, 162)),
            ContextData(),
            'trap',
            NotificationType(
                ObjectIdentity(oid)
            ).addVarBinds((oid, value))
        )
    )

    if errorIndication:
        print('Trap gönderilirken hata:', errorIndication)
    else:
        print('Trap başarıyla gönderildi!')


oid = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.32285.2.1.2.2.2.2.0'
value = Integer32(1)  
send_trap(oid, value)
```

**I can see this with snmp trap watcher:**

Frame Length: 96 bytes
Version: SNMPv2
Community: public
PDU Type: Trap v2
Request ID: 52D70A
Error Status: 0
Error Index: 0
OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
ASN.1 Type: Time Ticks 0x43 (67)
Value: 0 days, 00:00:00
OID: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
ASN.1 Type: Object ID 0x06 (6)
Value: .1.3.6.1.4.1.32285.2.1.2.2.2.2.0
OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.32285.2.1.2.2.2.2.0
ASN.1 Type: Integer32 0x02 (2)
Value: 1

I cannot see the trap data with the code below. Where am I making a mistake?

```
import tkinter as tk
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dispatch import AsyncoreDispatcher
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
import threading


def trap_callback(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName, varBinds, cbCtx):
    print("Trap mesajı alındı:", varBinds)
    for varBind in varBinds:
        oid, value = varBind
        oid_str = oid.prettyPrint()
        value_int = int(value.prettyPrint())
        if oid_str == '.1.3.6.1.4.1.32285.2.1.2.2.2.2.0':
            if value_int == 0:
                cbCtx.config(bg="green")
            elif value_int == 1:
                cbCtx.config(bg="red")
            elif value_int == 2:
                cbCtx.config(bg="yellow")

def run_dispatcher():
    transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Alarm Monitor")

device1_label = tk.Label(root, text="R Device", width=20, height=5, bg="green")
device1_label.pack(pady=10)

device2_label = tk.Label(root, text="L Device", width=20, height=5, bg="green")
device2_label.pack(pady=10)


transportDispatcher = AsyncoreDispatcher()
transportDispatcher.registerRecvCbFun(trap_callback)

udpTransport = udp.UdpSocketTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 162))
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(udp.domainName, udpTransport)


threading.Thread(target=run_dispatcher).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are referring to legacy APIs like `asyncore`, which are going away with Python 12. Where did you learn about PySNMP? Read https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/429 to understand the latest.